# What is the need for creating multiple child SA in IKE V2?

Tags: security, ipsec

In Security  Association,
I understand that after AUTH exchange a child SA will be created.But what is the need to create multiple child SA's and what is the difference between an IKE_SA and CHILD_SA ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1/ Multiple child SAs

- Although having single child SA seems to be sufficient there are cases where you really need multiple child SAs:

  - rekeying -- the process of rekeing is defined as establishing a new SA and then closing the old SA. There is a time period when both old and new SAs are valid.
  - different SAs for different traffic -- under some setups you might need to have a different level of protection for different services (e.g. AH for some unimportant traffic and ESP with strong parameters for the confidential one)

2/ IKE_SA vs CHILD_SA difference

- IKE_SA is the SA which protects the IKE traffic
- CHILD_SA is the SA which protects non-IKE traffic

Hope this helps a bit!

Disclaimer: It has been some time since I was dealing with this, so please do validate my thoughts